# Hide day and month widgets in date form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

This does not hide the month and day widgets entirely...

```
{% block date_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if widget == 'single_text' %}
            {{ block('field_widget') }}
        {% else %}
            <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
                {{ date_pattern|replace({
                '{{ year }}':  form_widget(form.year),
                '{{ month }}': form_widget(form.month, { 'attr' : { 'style': 'display:none' }}),
                '{{ day }}': form_widget(form.day, { 'attr' : { 'style': 'display:none' }}),
                })|raw }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock date_widget %}
```

...and this:

```
'{{ month }}': '',
'{{ day }}': '',
```

fails during validation.

**Any ideas how we can remove day and month widgets from the date form field?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date` type without the `month` and `day` parts is just a `year` type. So, why don't you create one instead of misusing the type meant for dates?

You could use the [`choice`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) type or create a `year` type based on it. You could also take a look at the [`years`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html#years) options of the [`birthday`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html) type and add a similar option to your new type.